# How do you declare strings inside brackets in Bicep?

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-bicep

The Bicep template for creating a virtual network has the parameter 'dnsservers'.  The expected value type is a string, but it's enclosed inside square brackets.  How would you set two IP addresses for it?

```
dhcpOptions: {
  dnsServers: [
    'string'
  ]
}
```

I've tried

```
param dnsservers string = '10.100.1.1, 10.100.1.2'
```

...but of course that fails, because

```
'10.100.1.1, 10.100.1.2' is not a valid IP address.
```

I should be able to set two IP addresses, but I don't know how, since "dnsservers" is a string and not an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.network/virtualnetworks?tabs=bicep#dhcpoptions), the dnsServers is an [array](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/bicep/data-types#arrays) of string:

```bicep
param dnsservers array = [
  '10.100.1.1'
  '10.100.1.2'
]
```

Also when you see brackets `[]`, it means it is an array so `['string']` means array of strings

Comment: That worked.  The first time I tried to follow the documentation, I didn't realize I could change the expected data type from string to array.

Comment: @egrok the brackets means it s an array so `['']` is an array of string